# How to fix "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest" in a NetBeans application that uses Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, netbeans, ejb, libraries

When trying to deploy an application to NetBeans that uses Apache HttpClient, the EJB container initialization fails. The most important error message is: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest".

Which libraries could cause conflicts or which ones am I missing? because I have gson-2.8.0, spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar, validation-api-1.0.CR3.jar, javax.mail.jar, commons-logging-1.2.jar , jacskon\httpcore-4.4.4.jar, jackson-annotations-2.15.2.jar,jackson-core-2.15.2.jar, jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar, commons-codec-1.9.jar, commons -logging-1.2.jar, httpclient-4.5.2.jar, httpcore-4.4.4.jar, jackson-annotations-2.15.2.jar, jackson-core-2.15.2.jar, jackson-databind-2.15.2 .jar, jackson-databind-2.16.zip, http-request-3.2.1.jar, httpclient-4.5.2.jar

It should be noted that it is not a maven project and I do not have the pom.xml

Comment: Update your question with all of the following: [1] The stack trace for the `NoClassDefFoundError`. [2] Details of how you created the project. (Is it an Ant project created in NetBeans?) [3] The versions of NetBeans and Java that you are using.